# Why there's no precision error when printing 0.1 as a double with many digits after point?

Tags: kotlin, floating-point, double, precision

The function (written in Kotlin) below

```
fun main() {
   println ("%.20f".format(0.1f))
   print ("%.100f".format(0.1))
}
```

prints

```
0.10000000149011612000
0.1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

If 0.1 can't be represented exactly as binary fraction why there's no precision error in the double version?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `float` has about 7 digits of precision, while `double` about 16.
Even if you tell it to print 20 or 100 digits, the actual value is still capped by the given precision. The double has the error too, although a smaller one.